# Issues using java.lang.Class as a parameter for a method

Tags: java

I have the following setup of classes/interfaces.

- Interface IFoobar
- Class BaseClass which implements IFoobar and is abstract
- Class ConcreteClassA which extends BaseClass
- Class ConcreteClassB which extends BaseClass
- Class ConcreteClassC which extends BaseClass

I have a method for which I need to pass instances of java.lang.Class for the above concrete classes. I am declaring it like so.

```
void doSomething(String id, Class<IFoobar> c)
```

However, when I try to compile, java complains with an error more or less like this:

```
doSomething(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<IFoobar>) in javaclass cannot be applied to 
        (java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<ConcreteClassA>)
        register("12345", ConcreteClassA.class);
        ^
1 error
```

I've only recently needed to use java.lang.Class to do things, so I am guessing I am missing something simple. I would have expected the typed class declaration to work like normal parameters in that the concrete classes are recognized as instances of the interface, but this apparently isn't the case.

I've tried various methods of casting, etc and either not had the desired results, or had code which isn't valid. So any ideas as to what I need to do would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you get instances of "Class"? Do you mean you're trying to pass an object of any class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable of type `Class<IFoobar>` can only hold a reference to a `Class<IFoobar>` object, not a `Class<ConcreteClassA>` object.

Change `Class<IFoobar>` to `Class<? extends IFoobar>`.

This behaviour is not particularly sensible for Class objects. It is much more logical for collections, where it stops you doing this:

```
void method1(List<IFoobar> list)
{
    list.add(new ConcreteClassA());
}

void method2()
{
    List<ConcreteClassB> list = /* something */;
    method1(list);
    // oops! we put a ConcreteClassA inside a List<ConcreteClassB>
}
```

Comment: Thanks @immibis, that looks to have solved the problem. I am by no means an expert on generics, but I read that as 'any class which extends (or implements in this case) IFoobar', is that right?

Comment: Yes. For the purpose of generics, `implements` and `extends` are both called `extends` - `Class<? implements IFoobar>` is invalid. Like I said, generics are a lot more logical when you think of the way the collections library uses them, rather than the way `Class` uses them. There are good reasons why you would want to `List<? extends IFoobar>` or `List<IFoobar>`, but there's not really a good reason to use `Class<IFoobar>` instead of `Class<? extends IFoobar>`.

Answer (score 0):

the only accepted value for `Class<IFoobar>` is `IFooBar.class`. If you want to accept `IFooBar.class` and all its subclasses, you should use `Class<? extends IFooBar>`

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with "Class"

Simply if you use

```
ArrayList<Object> x = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You get error: incompatible types

because, though the String class is a subclass of Object, ArrayList<Object> is a different type than ArrayList<String>. That is the nature of Generics.

You can use

```
void doSomething(String id, Class c)
```

Comment: Thanks @Chamil, I was considering using this but wanted to ensure that the 'Class' instance being passed to the method was one which implemented the IFoobar interface. By using class, I would expect I could pass a wider range of objects than intended.